# Why must a char array end with a null character?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char, null-terminated

Why does a char `array` have to end with a null character? Is there any reason that I have to add the null character to to every `char` array ?

It seems that they get treated the same way.

Comment: Some languages use "Pascal-style" strings which are length+chars.  C uses a NUL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, if you have a pointer to an array, then there is not way to determine the length of that array. As @AProgrammer points out, the designers could have left it at that and forced the programmer to keep track of the length of all character arrays. However, that would have made text processing in C even harder than it already is.

Therefore the language designers settled on a convention that would allow string length to be inferred by the presence of a null character indicating the end of the string.

For example, consider `strcpy`:

```
char *strcpy(char *destination, const char *source);
```

There is no way in C to determine the length of the array that the pointers `destination` and `source` point to. So, without the presence of a sentinel value to indicate the end of the string, the only other solution would have been to pass extra parameters indicating the length of the `source` string.

Of course, in light of modern security considerations, string processing functions that receive buffer length parameters have been introduced. But the computing landscape looked very different at the time that the null-terminated string was invented.

Comment: yes but, I mean if I did char arr[2]={'h','i'}; I guess the compiler knows the length of arr.

Comment: @AlexDannk Yes that is true. But it's clearly not useful if all strings are constrained to have the same length.

Comment: sorry! I didn't understand what you mean by that. you said it's useful for knowing the length of the array. but the compiler knows already the length of any array. so I dont find it useful

Comment: @Alex But you don't work with arrays when processing text. You work with pointers to arrays. And then you don't know the length of the array.

Comment: @AlexDannk: And what happens when you pass that string to someone else? The compiler cannot transmit the *size* of an array; when passed to a function, the array decays to a pointer. The size information is lost.

Answer (score 10):

A char array doesn't have to be null terminated (standard library functions which don't depend on this include `memcpy`, `memmove`, `strncpy` -- badly named this latest one --, `printf` with the right format string).

A NUL Terminated Character String (NTCS) needs by definition to be terminated by a NUL.  It is the format expected by string handling utilities of the C standard library and the convention used by most C program (in C++, one usually use `std::string`)

Comment: so it's like a convension!. but why did they make it like that. couldn't be much easier to make it not null-terminated. I dont get it. i read that for example when I pintout a null-terminated array the compiler will know when to stop printing. so is this null character is somehow useful to prevent printing the rest of junk characters . thanks!

Comment: @Alex In your proposed design, all strings would have to be the same length.

Comment: @Alex, the alternative to an end marker (such as NUL), is to have a length field.  In practice, working with a sentinel often simplify algorithms, and it allows you not to have a arbitrary maximal size for strings, without paying an overhead for all of them (yes, at the time choosing between a one byte or two bytes size field would have been hard, memory was tight but limiting oneself to 255 chars?  I think that it would have been the later which would have been chosen).

Comment: @AlexDannk Yes, the point of the null character is so that functions doing something with a string can check each character and when they find one that is null they know they're at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you want to use it as a string. Then all C/C++ string functions will search for the null char at the end, and if it's not there, they'll continue searching and sooner or later your application will crash.

If you only intend to use array chars as array of chars, never referring to them as strings, then no problem. It's exactly like an array of ints.

Comment: what about this. char arr[2]={'h','i'}; cout << arr; so why it doesn't crash since the compiler will not find the null character to end.

Comment: @Alex - It might seem to work sometimes, but the result is really undefined. We don't know the value of the next byte after the array - it just might be zero. In that case, the displayed value looks good. If not, the program might display garbage, or crash.

Answer (score 0):

In general there's no reason to do that, but you must know that every string is, by definition, a `char` array with null terminator. If your `char` array represents a string then  if you omit the null terminator every function working with C strings will not return the correct value or will behave differently than expected.

However `char` is a type like `int`,`float` or `double`, so you are free to create `char` array as you like, without the need for them to be null-terminated.