# getline skipping one character for char array

Tags: c++, getline

why cin.getline is skipping one character?

Here is code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char b[5];
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(b,5);
    cout << b;
   return 0;
}
```

if I removed cin.ignore(); then it will skip the last character..
Example If i input abcde it will show now bcde
When I removed cin.ignore();
it will show abcd

Comment: possible duplicate of [Program skips cin.getline()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835226/program-skips-cin-getline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra space to store a Null character. Change your string to

```
char b[6];
```

C strings are terminated with a Null character ( `'\0'` ), so if you need a string that can store 5 characters, you need to create one which can store 6 characters ( the extra space for a Null character )

So you can remove the `cin.ignore()` now as it reads the first character you enter and then discards it.

Try

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char b[6];
    cin.getline(b,6);
    cout << b;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know that, but why this causing the issue? Even I tried your method and input like abcde why it's skipping the first a? please try yourself and input abcde on your code.

Comment: @AsifMushtaq , I forgot to remove the `cin.ignore()`. Remove it and try it.

Comment: you mean I need always one additional size number to my required size? But sorry to bother you, can you explain why it's happening?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq , Yes. [why a char array must end with a null character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261672/why-a-char-array-must-end-with-a-null-character)

Answer (score 0):

Always take into account the NULL character (`\0`). Make sure there is atleast one extra space for it. If your input string is `n` chars long, your char array should be declared as `b[n+1]`, to accommodate the Null character. Null character is important because it acts a string terminating character, any proper string must be null-terminated.

So, for instance, you want to input a 5-char long string, declare the char array as 6 elements long: `char b[6];`

Comment: I know additional size can solve it.. But why it's happening?

Comment: Also, this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835226/program-skips-cin-getline

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using C++, you would be better off using std::string to avoid these little nuances.  It is important to know how C strings work though.